# Do we have option for spam protection in liferay

Tags: liferay, blogs, forum, spam

Liferay provides blogs and forums, in which I want to remove spam comments or content.

Is there any option liferay provides for it?

Before publishing any data by content should be spam filtered.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to take a look at the [Akismet plugin](https://www.liferay.com/marketplace/-/mp/application/21261870).

Comment: This plugin may not be feasible @ enterprise level, since more cost is associated with it

Comment: Seriously? Or did you mean @ personal level? In my world the enterprise cares for the job to be done. There's always a price. The enterprise can choose to pay you to implement a custom solution *and* upgrade the spam protection every time a new algorithm is in order. Or they pay a service to do this for them. Here you can pick the lower price *and* the better service at the same time. Win-Win.

Answer (score 1):

Else you can enable the workflow for both of the assets. If enable that then a moderator has to review the content and then only it will be published.
If you want to make that automatic, then you can go for the plugin as given by @Brandizzi.